# How can I borrow from a HashMap to read and write at the same time?

Tags: rust

I have a function `f` that accepts two references, one `mut` and one not `mut`. I have values for `f` inside a `HashMap`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn f(a: &i32, b: &mut i32) {}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    map.insert("1", 1);
    map.insert("2", 2);

    {
        let a: &i32 = map.get("1").unwrap();
        println!("a: {}", a);

        let b: &mut i32 = map.get_mut("2").unwrap();
        println!("b: {}", b);
        *b = 5;
    }
    println!("Results: {:?}", map)
}
```

This doesn't work because `HashMap::get` and `HashMap::get_mut` attempt to  mutably borrow and immutably borrow at the same time:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:15:27
   |
12 |         let a: &i32 = map.get("1").unwrap();
   |                       --- immutable borrow occurs here
...
15 |         let b: &mut i32 = map.get_mut("2").unwrap();
   |                           ^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
18 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

In my real code I'm using a large, complex structure instead of a `i32` so it is not a good idea to clone it.

In fact, I'm borrowing two different things mutably/immutably, like:

```
struct HashMap {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
let mut map = HashMap { a: 1, b: 2 };
let a = &map.a;
let b = &mut map.b;
```

Is there any way to explain to the compiler that this is actually safe code?

I see how it possible to solve in the concrete case with `iter_mut`:

```
{
    let mut a: &i32 = unsafe { mem::uninitialized() };
    let mut b: &mut i32 = unsafe { mem::uninitialized() };
    for (k, mut v) in &mut map {
        match *k {
            "1" => {
                a = v;
            }
            "2" => {
                b = v;
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
    f(a, b);
}
```

But this is slow in comparison with `HashMap::get/get_mut`

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR: You will need to change the type of `HashMap`**

---

When using a method, the compiler does *not* inspect the interior of a method, or perform any runtime simulation: it only bases its ownership/borrow-checking analysis on the signature of the method.

In your case, this means that:

- using `get` will borrow the entire `HashMap` for as long as the reference lives,
- using `get_mut` will mutably borrow the entire `HashMap` for as long as the reference lives.

And therefore, it is not possible with a `HashMap<K, V>` to obtain both a `&V` and `&mut V` at the same time.

---

The work-around, therefore, is to avoid the need for a `&mut V` entirely.

This can be accomplished by using `Cell` or `RefCell`:

- Turn your `HashMap` into `HashMap<K, RefCell<V>>`,
- Use `get` in both cases,
- Use `borrow()` to get a reference and `borrow_mut()` to get a mutable reference.

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, collections::HashMap};

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    map.insert("1", RefCell::new(1));
    map.insert("2", RefCell::new(2));

    {
        let a = map.get("1").unwrap();
        println!("a: {}", a.borrow());

        let b = map.get("2").unwrap();
        println!("b: {}", b.borrow());
        *b.borrow_mut() = 5;
    }

    println!("Results: {:?}", map);
}
```

This will add a runtime check each time you call `borrow()` or `borrow_mut()`, and will panic if you ever attempt to use them incorrectly (if the two keys are equal, unlike your expectations).

---

As for using fields: this works because the compiler can reason about borrowing status on a per-field basis.

Comment: But `iter_mut` works, without runtime checks, if I can jump to specific key via `IterMut`, then it would be possible to use `HashMap` without runtime check via `RefCell`.

Comment: @user1244932: `IterMut` guarantees that it only ever yields a single reference once, as per its semantics: you can never go back to an already yielded element via `IterMut`, and the elements so obtained borrow the original map (which thus cannot yield another element either).

Answer (score 5):

Something appears to have changed since the question was asked. In Rust 1.38.0 (possibly earlier), the following compiles and works:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn f(a: &i32, b: &mut i32) {}

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();

    map.insert("1", 1);
    map.insert("2", 2);

    let a: &i32 = map.get("1").unwrap();
    println!("a: {}", a);

    let b: &mut i32 = map.get_mut("2").unwrap();
    println!("b: {}", b);
    *b = 5;

    println!("Results: {:?}", map)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4ad4c635c33d6c3dc652cb4b68aeb563)

There is no need for `RefCell`, nor is there even a need for the inner scope.

Comment: What's changed is the introduction of [non-lexical lifetime](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2094). Basically the compiler sees that you aren't using `a` at the same time as `b` so it just drops `a` before the call to `get_mut`. This still fails if you use `a` after borrowing `b` mutably, i.e. by printing `a` right after you printed `b`.